# Listing the Pub/Sub subscription consumers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

It is possible for a service to do long polling on a pub/sub subscription. That obviously requires a TCP connection to be constantly open between the pub/sub service and the client. Is there any way to find out if a certain subscription has that TCP connection open?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to list all consumers for a Pub/Sub subscription, no. This would be tough as there are three different types of subscribers: [push](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push), [pull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#asynchronous-pull), and [streaming pull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#streamingpull). Only the last one maintains an open connection to the server.